# Android sync adapter trigger every 10 minutes

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I want to use sync adapter for calling a method once per day. As I do not need `Content Provider`, I defined a dummy provider just to make sync adapter work. The problem is that sync trigger about every 10 minutes, no matter what I set for time and never trigger on some devices. How can I make it work on all devices at exact time?

```
final Account account = new Account(username, "com.example.shop");
Bundle userData = new Bundle();
accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, "", userData);
// initial sync adapter
String AUTHORITY = "com.example.shop.syncAdapter.DummyProvider";
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY, 86400);
```

SyncAdapter:

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                          ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    Log.e("sync", "sync successful");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a **workaround** if this is urgent for you:

If your account is also just a dummy (as it seems), you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead of the sync adapter pattern. You then don't need the dummy content provider and so on. You can set a [timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY) - when to call a message or whatever - on the AlarmManager then.

Note that you don't have the sync android system features if you use an AlarmManager.